# RegEx to match C# Interface file names only

Tags: regex, visual-studio

In the Visual Studio 2010 "Productivity Power Tools" plugin (which is great), you can configure file tabs to be color coded based on regular expressions.

I have a RegEx to differentiate the tab color of Interface files (IMyInterface.cs) from regular .cs files:

```
[I]{1}[A-Z]{1}.*\.cs$
```

Unfortunately this also color codes any file that starts with a capital "I" (Information.cs, for example).

How could this RegEx be modified to only include files where the first letter is "I" and the second letter is not lowercase?

Comment: I'm no regex hacker, but it looks like it already should - I'm surprised that it doesn't.  That is, unless @BoltClock's edit was to add in the [A-Z]{1} portion of the regex...

Comment: Sounds like the plugin is doing a case-insensitive match, don't think there is much you can do about that. `Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: Yeah, the expression tests fine for me as well. It could be simpler but there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: No, I'm wrong I think, there is a way to do it in the pattern, just couldn't remember how to do it, not sure which takes precedence. See answer.

Comment: @Zannjaminderson: Nah, all I did was retag :)

Answer (score 5):

Your regexp should work as it is. It is possible that it is executed in *ignore case* mode. Try to disable that mode inside your regexp with `(?-i)`:

```
(?-i)[I]{1}[A-Z]{1}.*\.cs$
```

Comment: Your idea is very good, but OP's expression is not correct. In general, ok, but should be rewritten: unnecessary symbols group; exceeded, duplicate captures, etc

Comment: @abatishchev: you are right, it's not clean, however it works. I did a lazy copy & paste. As for the '^' part at the beginning everyone suggests, I cannot make the assumption that the input string contains only a file name and not the full file path (I don't use Power Tools).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
"(?-i)^I[A-Z].*\.cs$"
```

Sets case insensitve off first.

[Regular Expression Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: `.*` matches whitespaces and other unnecessary characters

Comment: @abatischev: BTW, if you want to be completely compliant, you should consider that a file name in Visual Studio can contain any character allowed by Windows for a file name, that is, any character which is not: /?:&\*"<>|#%, unicode control and surrogate characters, system reserved names, and are not "." or "..". That allows spaces, underscores, etc. In this particular case, there is probably no need to validate the complete conformity of the file name - if the file exists, it is already conforming, all we need is to check if it starts by something and ends by something.

Answer (score 1):

Filenames in Windows are not case-sensitive, so obviously Power Tools will be using case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
^I([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*){1}\.cs$
```

so

```
IMyInterface.cs // matches, MyInterface
IB.cs // B
IBa.cs // Ba
IC1.cs // C1
I.cs // don't
Information.cs // don't
```

[Prooflink](http://www.rubular.com/r/g3nLntvrWE)

Answer (score 0):

I based mine off the default patterns placed in there and used `^I[A-Z].*\.cs[ ]*(\[read only\])?$` - I think that there is a precedence question, though, so that if you leave the default `.cs` pattern matcher in there and add yours to the end, you might have yours hidden, because it matched the general one first.

And you can't re-order or delete them, so it's a little fiddly to get the ordering working well ...

FWIW, I don't think the case-sensitivity question (`(?-i`) makes any difference.